# Redirect stdout of one process to two processes

Tags: c, fork, pipe

Im having big troubles in doing what i said in title. 
Basically, i want a program, say broadcast.c, that accepts input from the user and then sends that input to the input of two processes.
So if would run this command:
./broadcast prog1 prog2

It would block awaiting the input from the user and then sending that input to prog1 and prog2.

Now, i want to use pipes, thing is, i dont know if i have to use 1 pipe or 2 pipes.

broadcast.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int fds1[2], fds2[2];
        char buffer[120];
        pipe(fds1);
        pipe(fds2);

        if (fork() == 0) {
            close(0);
            dup(fds1[0]);
            close(fds1[0]);
            close(fds1[1]);
            execl(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
        }

        if (fork() == 0) {
            close(0);
            dup(fds2[0]);
            close(fds2[0]);
            close(fds2[1]);
            execl(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
        }

        while(read(0, buffer, 120) != 0) {
            printf("lido: %s\n", buffer);
            write(fds1[0],buffer,120);
            write(fds2[0],buffer,120);
        }

        close(1);
        dup(fds1[1]);
        dup(fds2[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
```

I know this doesnt work and it may be messed up, so if you guys could help me out that would be great.

For now i just want that when i do:
./broadcast prog1 prog2
The user enters: Hello

The output is:
prog1 says: Hello!
prog2 says: Hello!

Basically prog1 and prog2 are just print using read on fd 0.

Comment: Hum interesting. Didnt know about that. But can it be done with simple forks and dups?

Comment: Not without some code to read the input FD and write the data to each output FD, as far as i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want a program, say broadcast.c, that accepts input from the user and then sends that input to the input of two processes. So if would run this command: `./broadcast prog1 prog2`

You could implement `broadcast` command using `bash`:

```
$ tee >/dev/null >(prog1) >(prog2)
```

`tee` reads from stdin and sends it to `prog1` and `prog2`. `tee` by default duplicates stdin to stdout therefore `>/dev/null` is used to suppress it.

There is also [`pee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pee) command from [`moreutils` package](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
$ pee prog1 prog2
```

It does exactly what you want. It uses `popen()` to run child processes. The implementation is very simple, here's the whole source code (`pee.c` from `git://git.kitenet.net/moreutils`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Licensed under the GPL
 * Copyright (c) Miek Gieben, 2006
 */

/* like tee(1), but then connect to other programs using
 * pipes _and_ output to standard output
 */

int
close_pipes(FILE **p, size_t i) 
{
    int ret=EXIT_SUCCESS;
    size_t j;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        int r = pclose(p[j]);
        if (WIFEXITED(r))
            ret |= WEXITSTATUS(r);
        else
            ret |= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t i, r;
    FILE **pipes;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    pipes = malloc(((argc - 1) * sizeof *pipes));
    if (!pipes) 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        pipes[i - 1] = popen(argv[i], "w");
        if (!pipes[i - 1]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can not open pipe to '%s\'\n", argv[i]);
            close_pipes(pipes, argc);

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    argc--;

    while(!feof(stdin) && (!ferror(stdin))) {
        r = fread(buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ, stdin);
        for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            if (fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), r, pipes[i]) != r) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Write error to `%s\'\n", argv[i + 1]);
                close_pipes(pipes, argc);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    exit(close_pipes(pipes, argc));
}
```

Comment: `pee` is interesting, but it is not standard facility, you have to install it (and have the possibility to install it). The source code is interesting, but it is not the best one to start with - if the purpose for @user3162721 was to learn something? Then maybe it's better to try to fix the above code and explain him what was wrong - that's what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done in shell:

```
FIFO_FILE=/tmp/fifo$$
mkfifo $FIFO_FILE
cat $FIFO_FILE | prog1 &
cat | tee $FIFO_FILE | prog2
wait # wait for everything to finish
rm -f $FIFO_FILE
```

If you insist on the C code... There are so many problems I have found in your code:

- duping the other end of pipe (0 instead of 1)
- close the other pipe in the child processes
- you should handle return value of `read`, the actual number of bytes read - and pass it to the `write` function
- you must close the child's ends of pipes in the parent
- parent should close its pipes afterwards
- unnecesasry `dup2` calls at the end of the program

From the number of mistakes I see you don't understand it (sorry...). But basicly I must commend you - you created the 2 pipes and the while loop, this core of the program was almost correct. I recommend you to start learning step by step on small examples:

**[Linux Documentation Project - pipes in C](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html)**

This valuable resource will teach you how to do pipes, how to redirect etc.

Here is my attempt to fix your code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fds1[2], fds2[2];
    char buffer[120];
    int size;

    pipe(fds1);
    pipe(fds2);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(0);
        dup(fds1[1]);
        close(fds1[0]);
        close(fds1[1]);
        close(fds2[0]);
        close(fds2[1]);
        execl(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(0);
        dup(fds2[1]);
        close(fds1[0]);
        close(fds1[1]);
        close(fds2[0]);
        close(fds2[1]);
        execl(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
    }

    close(fds1[1]);
    close(fds2[1]);

    while((size = read(0, buffer, 120)) != 0) {
        printf("lido: %s\n", buffer);
        write(fds1[0],buffer,size);
        write(fds2[0],buffer,size);
    }

    close(fds1[0]);
    close(fds1[0]);

    exit(0);
}
```

Note that you should handle all syscalls by checking for `-1` return value and the ERRNO by `perror`!

Comment: Thanks but i really have to do it in c code xD. +1 for doing in shell tho

Comment: In the other two programs, i should just read from fd 0?

Edit: Yes its kinda of a homework.

Comment: @user3162721 yes - that's what when they receive their input.

Comment: Hum, i tried the code. its not working tho. It shows stange input when i first exec the program but when i enter some text it just shows the print of the main process "lido ..."  im doing this on the prog1 (and prog2):

**#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
 char buffer[120];
 read(0,buffer,120);
 printf("teste1: %s\n", buffer);
 return 0;
}**

Comment: @user3162721 well, this site is not about other people debugging your code. I gave you the basic ideas and all the guidelines you need to advance in your work. You might come back later with more specific question on some specific problem, if you run into trouble.

Comment: @user3162721 it doesn't work because `read` will not place terminating zero character needed by `printf`. You may want to use `fgets(buffer, 120, STDIN)` which will read the input by lines and it places the zero character automatically.

Comment: the shell command can be [much simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20949402/4279). You should check the returned values from syscalls. In particular, your code might drop some content *silently* because the returned value from `write` is not checked.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 1) only if you install some non-standard packages - it is not everywhere - e.g. missing in our university server 2) exactly, that's what I say in my answer. It's up to OP to handle all the return values.

Comment: I did it guys. Using what @Tomas said and some other stuff i finally did it. Thanks a ton everyone!

Comment: @user3162721, great! So have you been able to fix your C code?

Comment: @Tomas yes. I wrote two simple programs that just read in cycle whats in stdin. Then in broadcast.c i just managed to correctly use two pipes and write to both of them. Then in my terminal i see something like:

prog1 said: ..
prog2 said: ..

So i think its done yeah :D

Comment: @user3162721 congratulations! You managed to do it the hard way! Have any of my advices help you in this process?

Comment: Yes because based on your code i realized i was managing the end of the pipes the wrong way.

Comment: @riotvan great, you grow by learning. Feel free though to mark the answer that help you most.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that streams can only go to one destination. You would need to open two streams and send one to each destination and there is no easy way I'm aware of to do that.

What may be simplest is to make prog1 just pass through any input it receives and send it on it's output, then you can just add it in the middle of the chain and it is effectively invisible to the other processes.

To expand:

in prog 1 - whenever it receives input on stdin - it as well as processing it outputs the same data on stdout. This means that you can add it into a chain `broadcast | prog1 | prog2` and the data will get passed through to prog2 as well as being processed by prog1.

Comment: Didnt understand your answer :s

Comment: I've added a bit more, see if that helps