# Piping functions with other commands in linux

Tags: git, bash, unix

I would like to pipe a function with normal commands in Linux. Please note that all these commands are put into a .sh script (I use Bash shell). For example, I have with me a command as follows:

`git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD -z | xargs -0 dirname | catch_exceptions >> extracted_dir_names`

I have written `catch_exceptions` as a function above this command and it contains 2 sed delete statements. If i pipe the two sed commands in the function they work but if i put them one after the other they don't. Could someone explain why it is like this and how a work around can be done? Thanks in advance.

This works:

```
function catch_exceptions {

    sed '/^\./d' | sed '\#this/path/alone#d'
}

pushd /path/to/direc
rm -f extracted_directories.txt
git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD -z | xargs -0 dirname | remove_duplicates | catch_exceptions >> extracted_directories.txt
cat extracted_directories.txt
popd
}
```

But when i replace catch_exceptions with:

```
function catch_exceptions {
    sed '/^\./d' 
    sed '\#this/path/alone#d'
}
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you show the working and non-working variants of the function? We can't readily guess what you did (or did wrong) without seeing what you did.

Comment: I have added the code to the above question. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the `|`. In other words, the second version fails because you're not piping the result of the first sed into the second sed. Note that you can still write it as two lines, the first line just needs to end with `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first function, the output of the first `sed` command is fed to the second, so when the first completes, the second does too.

With the second function, the output of the first `sed` is sent direct to standard output, and only when it finishes does the second `sed` start.  The second `sed` has its standard input still connected to the pipe, but the first one read all the data, so the second `sed` gets nothing to process.

If you want both `sed` commands to read from the same pipe, review [Two children reading from a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731790/two-children-reading-from-a-pipe), and consider using `tee` with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).  Also review [Redirect stdout of one process to two processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938782/redirect-stdout-of-one-process-to-two-processes).

Comment: Oh ok fine. So, i need to add the pipe after every sed. there is no way that I can direct the standard output to two(or more) sed in the function at the same time?

Comment: There are commands to assist.  The tee command writes to one or more files as well as standard output.  There is a 'pee' command which can write to one or more pipelines.  There may be other names for commands that do the same job; I called mine tpipe, for example.  You may be able to find more info searching on SO.  (Search terms '[c] pee' and '[c] tpipe' return relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to direct the output to more sed in the function you can use temporarily files.

```
sed '/^\./d' input.txt > tmp.txt
sed '\#this/path/alone#d' tmp.txt > output.txt
rm tmp.txt
```